# To the Azores by ferry

Tags: ferries, azores

Is there a ferry service from mainland Europe to the Azores? How would one get there without flying? I don't want to take a car with me.

I've found ferry services within the Azores and information that there is no ferry service between Portugal and the Azores, but wasn't able to rule out other possibilities.

Comment: There are cargo ships which call occasionally at Ponta Delgada to deliver freight that is impractical to send by air. These sometimes take passengers, and there are some tales to be found from those who have done it, and some hints of agencies who can arrange passage.

Comment: Lonely Planet forum reached the same conclusion: https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-western-europe/topics/lisbon-to-azores-by-ship

Comment: Note: there are cruise ships from UK to Azores You may ask and arrange with them to stay one week (or more) there, but they will do it only on low season (where they expect not to fill all cabins): in your case, you will cause them to have half time the cabin empty (and most important: no people spending on board).

Comment: Thanks everyone! I really hoped for a regular service. I'll check out the cruise and cargo ship options.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to prove a negative, but https://www.ferrylines.com only lists ferry lines between the individual islands of the Azores.

Comment: Ferrylines seem to be down for a long time now, here is an answer to the question though: https://azores.com/azores/travel-tips/azores-ferry

The answer is no. There is no ferry service between the Azores and Portugal.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://azores.com/azores/travel-tips/ferry) says there are no ferry from continental Portugal to the Azores.

A quick search seems to be confirming it.